# Can't figure out about saving files

Tags: objective-c, ios, nskeyedarchiver, property-list

I am trying to save my object to the file system on an iPad, but I seem to be doing something wrong.  Here is how I have archived the object:

```
NSString *localizedPath = [self getPlistFilePath];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", character.infoName];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:character];

fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
localizedPath = [localizedPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSLog(@"File Path: %@", localizedPath);

if(data) {
    NSError *writingError;

    BOOL wasWritten = [data writeToFile:localizedPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writingError];

    if(!wasWritten) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [writingError localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Now, this creates a plist file that I can see and read on the file system.  When I try to use the following to unarchive it though:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *directory = [self getPlistFilePath];
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error];
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(NSString *path in files) {
    if(![path hasSuffix:@"plist"]) {
        continue;
    }
    NSString *fullPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    IRSkillsObject *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; // get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS here...
    [data release];

    [characters addObject:object];
}
```

I get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The IRSkillsObject conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol.  You can see, I commented the line that I get the error on.

I am sure it's something I am doing wrong, but I just can't see it.  I have tried to step through with the debugger (placing a break point in the `initWithCoder:` method of the object) but I don't get any errors then.  In fact, it places the data in the object properly as I watch.  But once it's done loading the data, it gives the error.  I have tried using the `retain` method, but that doesn't help.

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error is found. Usually is because some data has been released but it is still needed in the code.

Maybe there is a property inside your IRSkillsObject not retained in `-initWithCoder:`

Comment: That was exactly it.  I am still new to objective c and memory management and such (my history is mostly in .net...).  When I was setting the data (i.e. `infoName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:kNameKey];`) I was setting the iVar for the object, which then released the item.  When I chagned it to self.[propertyname] (i.e. `self.infoName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:kNameKey];`) it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You are releasing `data` without allocating it.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
IRSkillsObject *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
[data release];
```

So try this:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
IRSkillsObject *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
[data release];
```

Comment: or remove the line [data release];

Comment: Ok, so perhaps it's not the above methods that's causing the problem.  If I replace `[NSData datawithContentsOfFile:fullPath];` with `[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];` it does the same thing.  Could there be something with my object?

Thanks

Comment: Are there other plist files in the same folder ? If so, delete them all and try to archive/unarchive again.

Comment: I have tried that and there was no change. Just to clarify on what I have done: The `IRSkillsObject` is a...compound class?  Because there is a lot of code that went into making the IRSkillsObject, I broke it down over multiple classes, each one inherits from another class until you get to the final one that inherits from NSObject.  I made sure that each class uses the `NSCoding` protocol and that each has the `-initWithCoder:` and `-encodeWithCoder:` methods in it.  Is there something that I may have missed by doing this?